# Touchpad scrolling not working in nautilus of 12.04

Tags: touchpad, mouse-scroll

My touchpad scrolling in ubuntu 12.04 in not working for the nautilus window manager. However it is perfectly working in the browsers when I have to scroll down the page.

Can I enable scrolling from somewhere or is this a bug?

Comment: Same problem here, there's a bug filed in Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/983910